# Multi-booting Arch Linux on an existing Ubuntu 20.10/Win7 dual boot- How do I go about it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a system that has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 20.10 installed on a 256GB drive. I have 30GB of free space into which I plan to install Arch Linux. I have successfully installed Arch within a VirtualBox system in my Ubuntu build,so I have a passable amount of familiarity with the Arch install process.

I plan on installing from a Live USB, if possible. Arch Wiki seemingly has [a page about this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_Arch_Linux_from_existing_Linux), but I am unsure if it is what I need, as it does not mention multibooting anywhere and might be centered on installing Arch from an external machine.

This is the output of `sudo parted --list` from Ubuntu:

```
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZ7LN256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  102MB   101MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      102MB   236MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      236MB   68.8GB  68.6GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      100GB   100GB   1049kB                                             bios_grub
 6      100GB   242GB   142GB   ext4
 4      242GB   256GB   14.1GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
```

(`/dev/sda7/` will be located between partitions 3 and 5. Currently it shows up as free space.)

How do I go about doing this? Can I just boot from the LiveUSB and follow the regular instructions, mounting the 30GB free partition as my root directory? How do I need to handle bootloading (currently using, apparently GRUB 2.04-1ubuntu35.1)?

Comment: This question may be better suited at the Arch Forums or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: That's fair enough, I'll ask there, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have problem installing since you're familiar with the installation process. But I find your EFI partition size might lock you down. The larger the size of the EFI the better to perform multi boot installation. As far as I understand, you're at the bare minimum. You should read about EFI partition size before doing anything further.

Comment: I might have Windows to thank for that. I'll research EFI partition resizing. Thank you.